# Stop cmd from beeping when connected to linux terminal via ssh

Tags: linux, windows-10, command-line, ssh, terminal

I use `cmd.exe` of Windows 10 to remotely connect to a linux server via ssh. But it keeps beeping when I press certain keys, for example, pressing `backspace` when it is empty after the prompt, or pressing `tab` for autocompletion. It only happens when I am using ssh but not when I use the same cmd program to operate locally. How can I disable this?

Comment: Whatever you're using on the remote side, apparently it generates bell characters and your local window reacts. Maybe you can reconfigure `cmd.exe` and make it silent; I don't know, I'm a Linux guy. Alternatively maybe you can reconfigure the remote program not to send bell characters in the first place. What program is this? A shell? Bash maybe? If the program uses the Readline library (Bash does) then you need to change the `bell-style` variable of Readline. Please [edit] and tell us the program, hopefully it uses Readline and I (or somebody else) will guide you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in bash shell, try putting "set prefer-visible-bell" in ~/.inputrc.

For more options and explanations, see:
https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/50997660.html

Comment: Your answer is half way there. Have you tested it? `set bell-style visible` is a command for Readline. Put it in `~/.inputrc` for a permanent solution which affects all programs using Readline. The same command in Bash sets positional parameters (like `set foo bar`). This is what the answer does, irrelevant to the problem. To make Bash pass the command to Readline, it should be `bind 'set bell-style visible'`. Put it in `~/.bashrc` for a permanent solution which affects Bash only. Feel free to improve the answer (keep it technical, don't mention me). In its current form the answer is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, Kamil.  Answer corrected.  I could have swore it used to be different, but so goes my memory!  I did test it this time by adding a single entry to the ~/.inputrc on win 10 cmd ssh client.